# Addition of numbers in array as string in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, addition

I am following these lines of code, but generating error when I do:

```
x = randi([0,9],1,20);
y = randi([0,9],1,20);
x_new = str2double(sprintf('%d',x));
y_new = str2double(sprintf('%d',y));
result = num2str(x_new+y_new) - '0';
fprintf('%4d',x);
fprintf('\n');
fprintf('%4d',y);
fprintf('\n');
disp('+');
disp('-------------------------------------------------------------------------')
fprintf('%d',result);
fprintf('\n')
```

The output I get (which is wrong):

```
9   6   1   3   0   5   4   9   8   4   8   1   3   9   9   7   6   3   9   1
   7   6   8   3   7   8   3   5   9   5   3   6   3   7   4   4   6   9   3   8
+
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1-272968385801777453-520
```

can someone please mention the mistake in running these lines. And help me to align (with same gap spaces) the result
the will be the addition of these numbers.
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your expected result?

Comment: The expected answer is:

   `1   9   5   4   9   6   4   8   5   5   6   3   2   5   8
   4   1   4   3   4   8   4   3   3   1   2   0   4   2   2
+
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  6  0  9  8  4  4  9  1  8  6  8  3  6  8  0`
This code is basically doing addition of big numbers, it works fine for 15 digits but not for 20

Comment: You are adding doubles, so limited by floating-point precision. You won’t get more than ~16 digits.

Comment: Please add clarifications to the question itself using [edit]. As you see, formatted text is impossible to read in comments. As @CrisLuengo said, you are seeing the limitations of numeric representation in programming.